# Role of Sound Miner in FX library creation?

Tags: soundminer, sound-libraries

Prepare yourselves for a noob question, but I'm not 100% clear on the role of programs like Sound Miner when creating a sound fx library.  Do I import all of my sounds into this program, tag each sound and then export from there?  Is there anything I'm missing in that regard and is there a way to do this without this program?  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

Everything you ever needed to know, right here:

http://designingsound.org/2010/12/frank-bry-special-methods-of-a-metadata-madman-part-1/

http://designingsound.org/2010/12/frank-bry-special-methods-of-a-metadata-madman-part-2/